# To extract strings between special characters using grep on mac

Tags: regex, bash, html-parsing, regex-lookarounds, text-extraction

I am trying to retrieve text between `{{` and `| translate` .

Input: testfile.txt

```
views/range.html:      <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="setRange(7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)">{{ '7 days' | translate }}</button>
views/widget.html:    <span class="state">{{phase}}/2</span> {{titles[phase-1] | translate}}
views/directives/widget.html:    <button class="btn" ng-disabled="selectedWidgets.length === 0" ng-click="phase = 2">{{ 'Next' | translate }}</button>
```

Expected result:

```
'7 days'
titles[phase-1]
'Next'
```

Tried so far:

```
grep "translate" | grep -o "'[^']*'" testfile.txt
#results
'7 days'
'Next'

grep '{\{\(.*\)|\translate%\1%' testfile.txt
#results
grep: invalid repetition count(s)

awk -F '{{|translate' '{print $2}' testfile.txt
#results
 '7 days' | 
phase}}/2</span> 
 'Next' |
```

I am doing this on macOS Sierra, version 10.12.4. Thanks!

Comment: if you could install GNU grep, it would be easy to get the needed result

Comment: Can you provide feedback on the answers below if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` for this extraction,

```
awk -F'[{}]' '{split($(NF-2),array,"|"); print array[1]}' file
 '7 days' 
titles[phase-1] 
 'Next'
```

The idea is to set the field-separator to `{}` so, that we can access fields within `{}` from the file. So `$(NF-2)` represents the second to last field which will contain lines like,

```
 '7 days' | translate 
titles[phase-1] | translate
 'Next' | translate
```

Over the above lines, if we use `split()` function with a `|` de-limiter, the first split field value will contain the value we are looking for.

---

OP wants to apply the `awk` commands to all the `html` files in the folder which can be done as

```
for file in /Users/my_app/src/*.html; do
    awk -F'[{}]' '{split($(NF-2),array,"|"); print array[1]}' "$file" >> alltranslatewords.txt
done
```

Comment: It is working fine. I am extending this to run on a folder  and save it to a file, `find /Users/my_app/src -type f -name "*.html" -exec awk -F'[{}]' '{split($(NF-2),array,"|"); print array[1]}' > alltranslatewords.txt`

Comment: did it:-marked, liked your comment :) and thanks for your help. Can you please help me to get as above.

Comment: I got this `awk: trying to access out of range field -1`. What does it mean?

Comment: The problem is some of the lines has other format. I fixed it. `for` is not recursive here!. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***BSD grep***(on OSX) has no support of `-P (--perl-regex)`.

Use the following ***perl*** approach:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if m{> ?\{\{\s*([^|\}]+?)\s*\| translate}' testfile.txt
```

---

`-n` option - causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

`-l` option - enables automatic line-ending processing

`-e` option - lets you specify a single line of code on the command line.

`print $1` - prints the first capturing group i.e. `([^|\}]+?)`

The output:

```
'7 days' 
titles[phase-1] 
'Next'
```